# SQLite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: id

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

I am programming an app for Android and decided to store a little bit in an SQLite Database.

I used following to create the database:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(TestPath);
db.CreateTable<TestClass>;
```

and that is the class:

```
class TestClass
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotNull, Column("messagetext")]
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    [Column("messagetype")]
    public int MessageType { get; set; }

    public TestClass(string mText, int mType)
    {
        MessageText = mText;
        MessageType = mType;
    }
}
```

When i run the app (no matter if debug or release) the following Error occures:

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: id
```

I already checked if it is called multiple times.
I already tried to change the name.
What i noticed is that it is always the first column. So in the first place i had not added the id because i don't realy need it. But without the id the same error occures with the next column.
I also tried to change linking. (No linking did not help)

I always cleaned and completly rebuilt the project and deleted the old app from the emulation.

Everything i tried did not help.
Any idea what i could try next?

Edit 25.05.2017:
I now tried it with less columns like this:

```
class TestClass
{
   public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Im still creating it with:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(TestPath);
db.CreateTable<TestClass>;
```

Did not help. There is only one simple property but what ever visual studio does, it tries to add that property as a column twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of tests and debugging I found the problem.

The included Nuget Package of SQLite was the problem. It is only able to create a table once. No matter what you do, if you created one table you cannot create another one or something else. Even if you delete the database.

It was solved after I changed the Nuget Package to another one with nearly the same functionalaty.